# Calculate the Utilization Distribution Overlap Index (UDOI) in QGIS or in R using a different package than adehabitat

Tags: r, qgis, adehabitathr

I have a series of home ranges of 2 different species and I need to calculate their overlap (UDOI, specifically). I created these home ranges using the ks package specifically because I wanted to use the plug-in method. Unfortunately it is not possible to use this method in the adehabitathr package, which would have been ideal because then I could have easily used kerneloverlaphr() to calculate the UDOI. But, that was not an option, so I used ks.

So now I've got kde lists or spatial polygons, or even shapefiles, of the KDEs. I can import this into QGIS and calculate the UDOI there. Or I could transform this ks output (somehow) into a file that I *could* use with kerneloverlaphr(). I cannot figure out how to do either, though. Could anyone suggest a way of either converting that data into something useful in the adehabitathr package, or how to calculate UDOI in QGIS?

I saw [this post](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/44389/how-to-calculate-utilization-distribution-overlap-index-udoi-in-arcgis-desktop), but I simply cannot understand the answer at all.

[This could be close](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72954161/how-to-create-an-estudm-object-from-utilization-distributions-created-with-gis)? But I'm not quite sure I understand it either.

Comment: Welcome to SO, Larissa. It is impossible to help without having code and data. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Comment: Hi @Friede, I don't think that's necessary here. I'm just asking if anyone knows how to calculate a UDOI in QGIS or if anyone knows how to convert a kde list into something that's useable in adehabitathr.